# Proper way to run wp_query from inside a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query

I am developing a plugin that needs to make a query of a custom post type and retrieve data and meta data from these posts. But anytime I run that query inside my plugin, no matter what admin new post page I pull up (in any post, custom post type, or page) there is data that is pre-filled in, and it is from the first custom post type I am querying in my plugin. So, for example, inside my plugin I have:

```
add_action('wp','myfunction');
function myfunction(){
$mcpt_query = array();

$the_query = new WP_Query('post_type=mcpt');

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
   $mcpt_query[] = array(
        'id'       => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'idkey', true ),
        'field1'   => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'field1key', true ),
        'title'    => get_the_title($post->ID)
    );
endwhile;
endif;
return $mcpt_query;
wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

And if the above is in my plugin, any post-new.php page pulled up in admin will be prefilled with the first post from that custom post type (mcpt), instead of giving me a blank new post page to fill out.

Any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: What happens if you don't attach it to an action?  Run the thing on an admin page directly so you don't do it on every page load.

Comment: even if I comment out the action, I still get the same data error.

Comment: @Stephen `wp_reset_postdata()` is never called because it is after the `return`, put it *before* the return and it should work. Moreover, if you don't want the function affect admin in any way, just put `if ( is_admin() ) return;` in first function line.

Comment: Actually, this plugin is all for admin, nothing for frontend, so I want it to run in admin. And I have moved wp_reset_postdata (and tried wp_reset_query) in the spot before the return to no avail. Still same data problem in any new post

Comment: BUT, it seems a combo of moving reset_postdata, and moving to a foreach loop and using get_posts instead of wp query seems to have done the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what solved it (although I am not sure WHY since any of the individual actions below did NOT solve it):

I got rid of the action, changed from WP Query to get_posts, and moved reset above return.

```
function myfunction(){
$mcpt_query = array();

$the_query = get_posts('post_type=mcpt');

foreach ( $the_query as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
$mcpt_query[] = array(
    'id'       => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'idkey', true ),
    'field1'   => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'field1key', true ),
    'title'    => get_the_title($post->ID)
);
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
return $mcpt_query;
}
```